# Capture 'text entering' in WPF on any window on all desktops

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Id like to be able to capture - on the OS windows level - when text is being entered - **in any window, on all desktops**.

Details - id like to have a wpf ( or winforms ) application that can hook in to an event ( perhaps cursor change or keyboard clicks ) on windows os level - so i can run some logic on the text being typed.

Any reference or example - or even a subject to research would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Seems kinda like a keylogger.  Studying how those are made might be a good starting point

Comment: that's a good idea man, thank you !

Comment: @Paparazzi  - so i should ask for the appropriate OS level event on the windows forums, and then come back to .net to understand how to use them ? Seems kinda ' over segregation'  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use win32 api (use setwindowshookex method) to do that
Read about it at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex

Comment: trying to work off the examples there I've run into many issues - any chance you can help out with an example ? :P